Java EE to JakartaEE (1.8 to 11)
I am moving an application from Glassfish to JBoss and upgrading Java 1.8 to Java 11 and saw the namespace is now Jakarta.
When interacting with ActiveDirectory I use the javax package for the connection to LDAP etc.
I dont see JakartaEE equivalent for
import javax.naming.Context;
import javax.naming.NamingEnumeration;
import javax.naming.NamingException;
import javax.naming.directory.*;
import static javax.naming.directory.SearchControls.SUBTREE_SCOPE;

which are the libraries used for this.
Any ideas on how to make this change or update for ActiveDirectory file of my application?
I tried replacing all javax imports with jakarta as I read and was instructed but it doesnt appear the naming package/classes are in jakarta for this change and i dont want to use some mishmash of Javax and jakarta.

Perhaps you should read some documentation and release notes before attempting major upgrades and migrations.

haha thank you for the response, i did, but the error was in my interpretation in terms of Jakarta replacing Javax libraries in the understanding that the libraries were duplicated in the Jakarta namespace

You dont have to make any changes as javax.naming is still compatible with Java 11 . It is still part of Java 11 and not part of Jakarta. Please refer the official documentation of Java 11 .
https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.naming/module-summary.html
